# Flask-WTForms auto-submit onchange with macro not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I would like my form to automatically submit once the last field detects an input. Here is what I have on the HTML side based on what I could find online...I know I'm probably missing something...

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% from 'bootstrap/form.html' import render_field %}

{% block content %}
    <img src="/static/logo.jpg"  alt="logo" width="50%" height="auto">
    <h1>Scan ABC...</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.A.label }}<br>
            {{ form.A(autofocus=true, required=true, size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.B.label }}<br>
            {{ form.B(required=true, size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.C.label }}<br>
            {% macro render_field(C(**{required=true, size=32, onchange="this.form.submit()"})) %}
            {% endmacro %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my form.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class Form(FlaskForm):
    A= StringField('A', validators=[DataRequired()])
    B= StringField('B', validators=[DataRequired()])
    C= IntegerField('C', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

I get this error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got '('
```

on this line

```
{% macro render_field(weight(**{required=true, size=32, onchange="this.form.submit()"})) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in other cases without auto-submit? In my case, I only use onchange="submit()", i.e.for example:

```
{{ filterform.search_text(class="form-control-button", onchange="submit()") }}
```

which leads to:

```
<input checked class="form-control-button" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" onchange="submit()" type="checkbox" value="y">
```

Maybe you want to try onchange="submit()"?

Comment: this worked: {{ render_field(form.weight, required=true, size=32, onchange="submit()") }}

but i still have to click outside of the field (i.e field loses focus) for the form to submit